# numbers are added to the current number

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a new names and numbers but when I add number it copies the original one and just adds the current number to the end. I'm not sure why. Anyone can help to understand why? Also I'm sure if I can add name and number in same state and how to do that?

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [ persons, setPersons ] = useState([{ name: 'Arto Hellas' }]) 
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')
  const [ number, setNumber ] = useState([{number: '040-123456789'}])
  const [ newNumber, setNewNumber ] = useState('')

    const addNameNum = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (persons.find(n => n.name === newName)) {
            window.alert(`${newName} is already added`)
            return false;
        }

        const nameObject = {
            name: newName
        } 
           setPersons([...persons,nameObject])

        const numObject = {
            number: newNumber
        }   
        setNumber([...number,numObject])
    }

    const handleNameChange = (event) => {
        setNewName(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleNumberChange = (event) => {
        setNewNumber(event.target.value)
    }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <form onSubmit={addNameNum} >
        <div>
          name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleNameChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
            number: <input value={newNumber} onChange={handleNumberChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
        {persons.map(person => (<p key={person.name}>
            {person.name}
            <br/>
            {number.map(num => num.number)}
            </p>))}
       
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: This construction adds new value to the array and  setNumber([...number,numObject]). This construction must replace old by new value setNewNumber(event.target.value)

Comment: It's happened you are use 
`setPersons([...persons,nameObject])` new person add in last of object in current object. if you needed show in first just use `setPersons([nameObject, ...persons])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing something like this.
import React, { useState } from 'react'

```
const App = () => {
  const [ persons, setPersons ] = useState([{ name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '123456' }]) 
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')
  const [ newNumber, setNewNumber ] = useState('')

    const addNameNum = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (persons.find(n => n.name === newName)) {
            window.alert(`${newName} is already added`)
            return false;
        }
        setPersons([...persons, {name: newName, number: newNumber}])

    }

    const handleNameChange = (event) => {
        setNewName(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleNumberChange = (event) => {
        setNewNumber(event.target.value)
    }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <form onSubmit={addNameNum} >
        <div>
          name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleNameChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
            number: <input value={newNumber} onChange={handleNumberChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
        {persons.map(person => (<p key={person.name}>
            {person.name}
            <br/>
            {person.number}
            <br/>
            </p>))
          }
     </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

It appears that in your app that a name matches a number so why not store them in the same data structure?